# Is there a way to make a notification in Google sheets that is based on a date or a percentage?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, sparklines

I'm working on creating a house maintenance spreadsheet and want to create a notification popup or sparkline that is visual that shows me the the completion level of the tasks. Is there a way to make this happen? I can create individual sparklines for each task, but I wanted a sparkline or notification that covers a room, so the kitchen has multiple items. I can make the sparkline for the indiv items, but not for the kitchen, so when the "kitchen" header turns red, then I know something within the collapsible group needs to be tended to.

I've been able to get the basic sparkline to work but nothing beyond that.

Comment: Notification falls outside of Google Sheets capabilities alone, are you open to using Google Apps Scripts along with it to accomplish this? Also please share a reproducible sample sheet so we can see and understand how your data works in your Google Sheets.

Comment: @Babanana Yes I'm 100% open to the apps. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAePg33AVhnBxEQuTnVoc23CzSPww85k-XKSZW-YkH4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi! I understand that you want everything as secure as possible by any chance you can have something that will show me how your data works inside and try to remove an sensitive information that you are not comfortable sharing. I cannot see what was on the hidden rows on your Google Sheets. Thank you.

Comment: @Babanana I opened all the groupings and made it able to comment. let me know if that works!

Comment: Thank you for that. Let me check and see what I can do.

Comment: May I ask for an edit access for the sheet so I can make the changes on my behalf to test out the possible options I can provide for you.

Comment: @Babanana https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAePg33AVhnBxEQuTnVoc23CzSPww85k-XKSZW-YkH4/edit?usp=sharing Sorry! Went to bed!

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I got this what you need is some sort of notification in terms of the progress of each room, the progress will be determined on how much room is on good status. May I ask are you looking forward to following the Red which is less 50%, then 51 to 69 is yellow and 70 is green? Please share with me about the thresholds of your expected results. Thank you.